# Append to page from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using ajax to get an svg, it returns something like this:

```
#document<!--Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)--><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" width=​"308.647" height=​"310.838" viewBox=​"0 0 308.647 310.838">​…​</svg>​
```

How can I then add this to my page?

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $('.chat').append(data.responseText);
        $('.chat').append(data.find('svg'));
        $('.chat').append(data.body);
    }
});
```

Comment: 'No luck' with such vague questions either..

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery's get and append functions like so:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadedContent" />
    </body>
    <script>
        $.get("contentToLoad.html", function(data) {
            $('#loadedContent').append(data);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

contentToLoad.html

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

OR

Try using [jQuery's load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) it worked great for me in the code below:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="loadedContent" />
    </body>
    <script>
        $('#loadedContent').load("contentToLoad.html");
    </script>
</html>
```

contentToLoad.html

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

You could just add a div at the bottom of your page, and it would "append" it